# Swift - Importing Custom File

Tags: ios, swift, file-extension, info-plist

I am trying to import and open a custom file in my app using the tutorial below

https://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/importing-data-via-custom-file-types-in/

This is how my info plist looks like
[image]

When I drag the file with the extension ".AMarkUp", the app just crashes

> 2019-03-11 11:28:37.661461+1100 Project[15404:836338] *** Assertion
>   failure in -[UIApplication _applicationOpenURLAction:payload:origin:],
>   /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKitCore_Sim/UIKit-3698.93.8/UIApplication.m:6851
>   2019-03-11 11:28:37.682291+1100 Project[15404:836338] *** Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
>   reason: 'Application has LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace key, but
>   doesn't implement application:openURL:options: on delegate
>   '

How can I fix this issue doesn't "implement application:openURL:options: on delegate"?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Try reading the error message. It tells you exactly what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement the specified `UIApplicationDelegate` method in your AppDelegate.swift file.

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
    // handle the file here

    return true // or false based on whether you were successful or not
}
```